# upload multiple child docs not associating to parent list item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Parent List and a Child Library. 1 Parent to many Children.

The Child Library has a required column of Parent List Item, when you upload 1 new document the "new Item" dialog appears presenting the ability to select the required Parent field.

The problem is, when you select Upload Multiple on the Child library, the docs are uploaded to the library with no opportunity to select a parent. The documents are available in the library, they're orphans until and unless you individually edit properties & assign a Parent List Item.

How do you upload multiple children docs w/ immediate association of parent list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of multiple document upload - you can't set metadata at upload time, so required fields don't get set, so the item is in an orphan state. If appropriate, you could set a default value for your required field.

Comment: Can i workflow or java my way into populating that parent field(assuming,lets say,the parent is "selected" in the parent list)?

Comment: If you have a way to automatically determine the correct value then you can do so via setting up a default value for the field, or implementing more complex logic in a workflow or event receiver.